# Разница показателей свободного места на диске в Mac

Tags: macos, mac, apple, hdd

В общем у меня 250 гб на маке, смотрю через "Хранилище"- свободного 127 ГБ, а если глянуть через "Дисковую утилиту", то 63 ГБ.

Какой из них релевантный?)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сложно выбирать из 2х, найдите третий источник данных

Comment: что говорят `du` и `df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реально свободный объём на текущий момент это столько, сколько показывает Disk Utility. Если посмотрите ниже (на скриншоте не видно), то увидите сумму разницы между этими двумя значениями (purgeable) - то, что вам мак может освободить при необходимости через фичу Optimize Mac Storage (настраивается нажатием кнопки "Управлять" с первого скриншота), речь про данные, которые удаляются локально и в будущем будут загружаться по запросу.